# What does "deaths feared" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-45068113). It was in the headline. Here it is:

> Russian helicopter crashes, **deaths feared**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a combination of the way news headlines are written, the fact that, especially in online news sources, stories are updated as more news comes in, and passive voice.

The first thing that is known is 'A Russian helicopter has crashed' > headline 'Russian helicopter crashes'.

The second thing that is known is 'It's bad. We (the helicopter company/air force, police) are afraid that people have died. We are afraid that there are deaths. Deaths are feared' > headline 'Deaths feared'.

A later headline might be 'Deaths confirmed' (we have confirmed that some people have died, but we don't know how many yet' and an even later one might be '17 deaths confirmed, more feared' (we have confirmed that 17 people have died, and we fear that even more have also died).

News headlines often use special, shortened forms of English called '[headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)'.

Comment: On a tv news program today, I saw the headline - Russia: 18 killed in helicopter crash. My example of 17 was a complete guess!

Answer (score 2):

Because it's headlinese, you have to guess the omitted words. Usually [forms of *to be* are omitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), so we guess

> Deaths **are** feared.

Note that this is passive and that *fear* means

> [fear](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fear)
>   verb
>   [ T; not continuous ] FORMAL **to be worried or frightened that something bad might happen or might have happened:**
>   [ + (that) ] *Police fear **(that)** the couple may have drowned.*
>   *FORMAL **It is** feared (that) as many as two hundred passengers may have died in the crash.*
>   *We huddled together, fearing we might be killed.*
>   [ + to infinitive ] *Fearing **to** go herself, she sent her son to find out the news.*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

In other words, people (police, officials, doctors, etc.) are worried that there are deaths (due to the crash).